# Python code works in one environment but gives an error in another

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a python script that works in my DEV environment. I used cx_freeze to create an EXE of this script and am calling the EXE from a Windows batch file. When I run the Windows batch file on my DEV environment, the script executes successfully without any errors. I then moved the cx_freeze build folder to a different environment and tried to execute the same Windows batch file and now I get all sorts of errors with the code. Is there anything additional that needs to be done when you move an EXE created with this process to a different environment? I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: NameError: name 'op_fn' is not defined. The 'op_fn' is a variable defined in the script and it does not throw this error in the DEV environment.

Comment: You have your answer. In the DEV environment `op_fn` is defined and when you move the folder it is not. What defines `op_fn`?